# Team foundation server retrieving non XAML build information

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2015. I'm having a problem in retrieving non XAML build information from my C# console App using the TFS API. Actually, for one project we have setup for XAML Build definations and for another project, it is non-XAML one. I am able to connect the TFS projects and able to get the XAML defination lists. However, while trying to fetch the Non-XAML definations or builds, it is always an empty array.My code is below,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var tfsUri = (args.Length < 1) ? new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerUri"]) : new Uri(args[0]);
        var userCreds = new NetworkCredential(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tfs.User"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tfs.Password"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tfs.Domain"]);

        // var tfsServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri, userCreds);
        var tfsServer = new TfsConfigurationServer(tfsUri, userCreds);
        tfsServer.EnsureAuthenticated();

        //// Get the catalog of team project collections
        var collectionNodes = tfsServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection }, false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

        //// List the team project collections
        foreach (var collectionNode in collectionNodes)
        {
            //// Use the InstanceId property to get the team project collection
            var collectionId = new Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
            var teamProjectCollection = tfsServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);

            //// Get a catalog of team projects for the collection
            var projectNodes = collectionNode.QueryChildren(new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.TeamProject }, false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);
            foreach (var projectNode in projectNodes)  
            {
                /*
                Console.WriteLine("Collection: " + teamProjectCollection.Name); // Print the name of the team project collection
                Console.WriteLine(" Team Project: " + projectNode.Resource.DisplayName);    // List the team projects in the collection
                Console.WriteLine(" Team Project Id: " + projectNode.Resource.Identifier);
                 */

                //// Get a catalog of team builds for the collection
                var buildDefinitions = new BuildDefinition();

                // var buildDetailList = buildDefinitions.GetBuildDefinitionListFromProject(teamProjectCollection, projectNode.Resource.DisplayName);
                buildDefinitions.GetBuildDetailsFromProject(teamProjectCollection, projectNode.Resource.DisplayName, projectNode.Resource.Identifier);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLogger.LogError(ex);
    }
}

public class BuildDefinition
{
    public void GetBuildDetailsFromProject(TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsProjectCollection, string projectName, Guid projectId)
    {
        var buildService = tfsProjectCollection.GetService<IBuildServer>(); // (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));

        var buildDefinitionsList = GetAllBuildDefinitionsFromTheTeamProject(buildService, projectName);
        foreach (var buildDefinition in buildDefinitionsList)
        {
            var bdentities = new BuildDefinitionEntities
            {
                ProjectId = projectId,
                ProjectName = buildDefinition.TeamProject,
                BuildTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(buildDefinition.Id),
                BuildTypeName = buildDefinition.Name,
                ProjectDetailPath = string.Format("{0} > {1}", buildDefinition.TeamProject, buildDefinition.Name)
            };

            var buildDetailSpec = buildService.CreateBuildDetailSpec(buildDefinition);
            buildDetailSpec.InformationTypes = null; // for speed improvement
            buildDetailSpec.MinFinishTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-21); // to get only builds of last 3 weeks
            buildDetailSpec.MaxBuildsPerDefinition = 1; // get only one build per build definintion
            buildDetailSpec.QueryDeletedOption = QueryDeletedOption.ExcludeDeleted; // get only active builds
            buildDetailSpec.QueryOrder = BuildQueryOrder.FinishTimeDescending; // get the latest build only
            buildDetailSpec.QueryOptions = QueryOptions.All;

            var buildDetailList = buildService.QueryBuilds(buildDetailSpec).Builds;

            //// List the team builds for the collection
            foreach (var buildDetail in buildDetailList)
            {
                bdentities.BuildId = buildDetail.RequestIds[0];
                bdentities.BuildName = buildDetail.BuildNumber;
                bdentities.ArtefactsPath = buildDetail.DropLocation ?? "No Artefacts";
                bdentities.BuildCompleted = Convert.ToDateTime(buildDetail.FinishTime) > Convert.ToDateTime(buildDetail.StartTime)
                                                ? Convert.ToDateTime(buildDetail.FinishTime)
                                                : Convert.ToDateTime(buildDetail.StartTime);
                bdentities.BuildStatus = buildDetail.Status.ToString();
                bdentities.SourceGetVersion = buildDetail.SourceGetVersion ?? string.Empty;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildDetail.Quality))
                {
                    bdentities.BuildQuality = buildDetail.Quality;
                    bdentities.BuildQualityChangedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(buildDetail.LastChangedOn);
                }

                BuildDefinitionDbOperations.ManageTfsBuildDefinitions(bdentities);


            }
        }
    }
    private static IBuildDefinition[] GetAllBuildDefinitionsFromTheTeamProject(IBuildServer buildServer, string projectName)
    {
        var buildDefinitionSpec = buildServer.CreateBuildDefinitionSpec(projectName);
        buildDefinitionSpec.TriggerType = DefinitionTriggerType.All;
        buildDefinitionSpec.Options = QueryOptions.Definitions;

        return buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions(buildDefinitionSpec).Definitions;
    }
}
```

Actually, I am new to this Tfs system. Would you please guide me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For the vNext/non-XAML build system you have to use the TFS REST API; you can find the details [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/build/definitions#Getalistofbuilddefinitions)